# Web interface of tunneled instance unreachable

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

Situation:
I'm using windows 10 if that matters.
I'm on a work VPN in order to reach some Linux servers with webservers installed on them. I also have WSL2 installed on my system. Using bash I am able to successfully create a tunnel to said server, where I use a specific port and bind it to my localhost on my port 55555.

Now prior to yesterday this setup worked. Now when I start the tunnel it is successful, but the web interface will not show. Of course I verified that it is up and colleague's are still able to reach it. Tunnelling will not work without the VPN so that is excluded as well.

The only network change I have done is installing "Docker Desktop for Windows". I have checked the hosts file and whilst the docker software did make changes to it, commenting them out did not solve my issue. It also seems that the docker software operates on different a different network segment, so that should also be no issue.

What might have caused this and is it a known issue?

[EDIT]
It's not just browsers it seems. A simple Post call also directly quits saying "ECONNREFUSED".

Comment: If you uninstall Docker, does it help?

Comment: Haven't tried that, but I have tried shutting it down (as in the entire service) and that made no difference.

Comment: So I uninstalled docker desktop en rebooted. Now the interface is functional again ..... I really wonder why (and I kind of need docker so I have to find a solution).

Comment: Perhaps install Docker inside WSL?

Comment: @harrymc: That was my second try indeed. Thanks for the suggestion. If that works then I really wonder why it would.

Comment: Much to my surprise the problem returned, even before installation of docker. Now I'm totally confused.

Comment: I don't know why installing Docker Desktop for Windows has loused up your setup, this shouldn't have happened. If System Restored is enabled, you might consider rolling back to before this was done.

Comment: Curiously enough I just rebooted and retried and it worked again. This OS is so random. I guess the solution was to uninstall docker desktop and just reboot when you encounter something. @harrymc: can you write this in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the poster was to uninstall Docker Desktop for Windows
and reboot.

This works most of the time, but may happen again.

Whenever the problem happens again, the solution is again to reboot once more.